# Getting the next element in a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say that we have this html code

```
<div id="test">
     <h2>Title</h2>
     <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

And this jQuery

```
$("#test h2").text("Changed Title");
```

Now what is the correct way to continue down to the `<p>` and also change it's text, without going up one level.
Like `next()` will only look for the next h2, but is there something that gets the sibling independent of element type. Something like `next("p");` maybe?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next` chooses the next element: by default it does not only select an element of the same type.

```
$('#test h2').next();      // selects the p
$('#test h2').next('p');   // selects the p
$('#test h2').next('h2');  // does not select the p
```

Unless you provide a selector, `next` *will* choose the next sibling element.  You can therefore do this:

```
$('#test h2').text('Changed title').next().text('Changed text');
```

Answer (score 2):

The command your looking for is `siblings("p")`

Here is your example, updated:

```
$("#test h2").text("Changed Title").siblings('p').text('test');
```

Answer (score 2):

`.next( 'p' )` will do the trick:

```
$("#test h2").text("Changed Title")
             .next( 'p' )
             .text( 'Another change' );
```

From the [jQuery docu](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

See [example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GmuxG/).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, you can do it by using the `.next('p')` method:

```
$("#test h2").next('p').text("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

`.next('p')` will indeed work. Just chain it at the end. like this:

`$('#test h2').text("Changed Title").next('p').text('I changed too');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test h2").text("Changed Title").siblings().text("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you suggested,

```
$("#test").next("p").text('yada');
```

or even better:

```
$("#test h2").text("Changed Title").next("p").text('yada');
```